# How to modify program search path?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and I have recently encountered a problem. Previously whenever I  typed the name of a program that was not installed in the terminal, I would get a list of suggested packages to "sudo apt-get install".

Recently however, whenever I type a program in to try and install it, the terminal just says

```
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure the reason why it's doing this is because a while back I wanted to be able to execute Python scripts in Python 3 without having to explicitly type in python3, but whenever I typed in python it just executed the Python 2 interpreter. I think the file python was a symbolic link pointing to the python2 executable and I tried to change it to the python 3 executable, but somehow I screwed up and now whenever I type in a program that's not installed, it just displays the above message instead of suggesting a package.

I'm not sure how to fix this so I was wondering it anyone could help. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If you actually managed to do what you wanted, you really messed things up, since a lot of applications depend on the right reference: python => python2, python3 => python3. It is hard to say what you did, but at least you should fix these references if you remember what you did.

Comment: Agree. Undo whatever you've done or let us know so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/python` should be a symbolic link to whatever version of python you wish to use. On my default system, it links to python2.7, which is also in `/usr/bin`, but is an executable, not a link.

I also have python3.4 in `/usr/bin`; if I wanted to use that instead of python2.7, I would simply redefine the link using the `ln` command, like so:

```
sudo ln -sT /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python
```

*-s creates a symbolic link;  -T means treat the target as a normal file, not a directory.*

If the python link existed, you would need to delete or rename it.

This should not have anything to do with the path at all.

I feel obliged to mention that you should never make modifications using `sudo` unless you understand what you are doing (especially know how to undo it, or at least write down the exact steps so you can ask), or you are instructed on exactly what to do by a trusted source (and it's best to understand what it's doing even in that case).  That is the whole reason `sudo` requires special permissions and a password.